# AJAX form submit (with a file) to Symfony but $form->isValid returns false

Tags: ajax, angularjs, forms, symfony

I use some Angular JS code to submit a file and some other fields (and a CSRF token) to a Symfony controller.

```
var formObject = new FormData;

formObject.append('email',      self.careers[index].application.email);
formObject.append('motivation', self.careers[index].application.motivation);
formObject.append('resume',     self.careers[index].application.file);
formObject.append('jobID',      self.careers[index].id);
formObject.append('_token',     self.CSRF);

$http.post('/app_dev.php/jobs/apply', formObject, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
}).success(function(){
    self.careers[index].application = {};
}).error(function(){
    // TODO: Explode on error
});
```

All is good and well until the information gets to my controller, where everything seems to just blow up.

```
public function applyAction(Request $request) {
    $jobApplication = new JobApplications();

    if (!$jobApplication) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find JobApplications entity.');
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($jobApplication)
        ->add('jobId')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('coverLetter')
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $jobApplication->upload();

        $em->persist($jobApplication);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $response = 'some success message';
    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Six hours of debugging both Symfony and JS, searching around the vast internet for answers and banging my head against the desk later I found out that:

- `$request` contains all the variables I post.
- `$form->isValid() = FALSE`
- `$form->isSubmitted() = FALSE`
- If I change from 
  `$form->handleRequest($request)` to `$form->submit($request)`, `$form->isSubmitted() = TRUE` but `$form->isValid() = FALSE`
- If I remove the validation, Symfony throws a HUGE error saying that all properties of `$jobApplication` are null.

I am fairly new (~4 months) to Symfony so I figured I must be doing something wrong. All other similar questions on SO did little to solve my dilemma.

## Update

`var_dump($form->getData());` returns that all my form field elements are `null`, even after `$form->handleRequest($request)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method createFormBuilder create form with default name "form"

```
public function createFormBuilder($data = null, array $options = array())    
{    
return $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, $options);    
}
```

So

```
$form->handleRequest($request)
```

looking data in

> form[email],  form[jobId], etc..

Try use

```
$form->submit($request->request->all())
```

Instead

```
$form->handleRequest($request)
```

**Update**

Seems angular.js post data in JSON format. So first need get raw data from request and then decode it before submit

Comment: It seems that's why the $form->handleRequest fails. In the end I had to find a solution fast so I went with pre-rendering the form and submitting it through a normal post.

Comment: Dealing with this issue in Symfony3 with a normal form submit (PUT). Sounds like a bug to me. The route is reached with the appropriate method. How is it that submitted is false?